# How i can rewrite this link?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule !

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /shop.php?cat=$1&catn=$2 [L]
```

and the link is

```
http://www.logromania.xyz/shop.php?cat=81&catn=Shard%20Pantofi%20lux%20Dama%20Femei%20Pantofi%20piele%20Dama%20comozi%20Pantofi%20Italia%20dama%20pret%20ieftin%20pantofi%20casual%20dama%20Bucuresti%20Tirgu%20Jiu%20Brasov%20craiova%20Timisoara%20Iasi%20Constanta%20Deva%20bacau%20Buzau%20galati%20Braila%20Oradea
```

it should be

```
http://www.logromania.xyz/cat/81/Shard%20Pantofi%20lux%20Dama%20Femei%20Pantofi%20piele%20Dama%20comozi%20Pantofi%20Italia%20dama%20pret%20ieftin%20pantofi%20casual%20dama%20Bucuresti%20Tirgu%20Jiu%20Brasov%20craiova%20Timisoara%20Iasi%20Constanta%20Deva%20bacau%20Buzau%20galati%20Braila%20Oradea.php
```

But is not working ! Were or tha's the problem ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a more sophisticated .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=([0-9]+)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catn=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?shop.php$ /cat/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

For a good explanation on how this works visit http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/

Looka at examples 10 and 11.

To test your RewriteRules you can use this online test tool: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Nice, it's work . I don't rly know how to use rewrite, now i get a 404 error page..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9]+)/(.*).php$  /shop?cat=$1&catn=$2
> ```